# Generic method for finding control on a page does not compile

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a generic method. Basically I want to use the method to search for an element on a page and return some different PageObject accordingly.

```
public T NavigateToTab<T>(string tabName)
{
    AdminConsole result = SelectOnNavElement(tabName);
    return new T(result);
}
```

Hovewer, it does not compile. Why?

Comment: `new T(result)` is not syntactically valid. Add a parameter for a `Func<AdminConsole, T>` to construct the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, it does not compile. Why?

Because `T` is a generic type, and the compiler can't guarantee that any `T` will have a constructor taking an `AdminConsole` as a parameter (as there is no such constraint).

One way is to pass a `valueFactory` delegate to your method, which can generate the proper `T` value given an `AdminConsole` instance:

```
public T NavigateToTab<T>(string tabName, Func<AdminConsole, T> valueFactory)
{
    AdminConsole result = SelectOnNavElement(tabName);
    return valueFactory(result);
}
```

And consume it like this:

```
void Main()
{
    Func<AdminConsole, AwesomeClass> classCreator = adminConsole => 
                                                        new AwesomeClass(adminConsole);
    var result = NavigateToTab("tab", classCreator);
}
```